# Hide multiple rows

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am fairly new to SSRS reporting. I have a report with the following structure:

[image]

How can I hide multiple rows (for example if value1, value2, value3 = empty, hide all three rows including heading1) without having an expression in each row property like:

```
=IIF(Isnothing(Fields!STILLEN_TEXT_KIND_1_VORNAME.Value),True,False)
```

Is there a way to define this globally?

Comment: Heading1,2 etc is grouping and text1,2,..,6 is detail?

Comment: If there is no data for the row, and the heading is actually a rowgroup then neither the rows or header will show without you doing anything.
If this does not help, share a screenshot of your entire design, including any row or column groups and also a sample of data from your dataset. I suspect, if you are having to write expressions to hide empty rows then your report and/or dataset design is fundamentally wrong. But as bad as that might sound the solution may be really simple

Comment: I need to adjust the report it looks like everything is detail, even the heading

Comment: Difficult to help without more detail about your report design

Comment: As I said, share the report design and he output from your dataset or it's difficult to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this tablix you can use nested grouping

Parent grouping would be for the Heading
Child grouping for the TextX - ValueX

In the filter of the child grouping, set the display option with your expression.

This way, it will only be applied to the rows of the child grouping without having to duplicate this expression on every row which would make maintenance much more difficult